# unable to access USB in virtualbox

Tags: linux-mint, usb, windows, virtualbox

I am using Linux mint 16. I have installed virtualbox and create two vhd. One is windows server 2008 and another one is windows 7. In settings, i have enabled both options to enable USB, also installed virtual box extension pack still can't access USB. I don't know what change should i make whether with host machine or guest or anything other to access USB in virtualbox.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) explain what you are using as a host OS ii) which OS has problems with USB? Is it the Windows running in the virtual machines? iii) what are these settings you have activated? Could you show a screenshot of the settings window?

Comment: i) host OS is linuxmint16 ii) USB is working perfectly in host OS. yes, windows is running in a virtual machine. iii) settings are Enable USB Controller and Enable USB 2.0 Controller. right now i don't have a screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use USB in your VM your user must be a member of the *vboxusers* group. 
To achieve this open a terminal window (in the host) and type

```
sudo adduser <youruser> vboxusers
```

Then log out and log in again.